# cakePHP: validating data in controller (hasMany)

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have the following problem:
I need to validate data in a controller, which is passed by a form. The special thing: The fields from the form are not present in the database, BUT in the $validate-Array. - Which should afaik not be a problem.
 Another thing is, that the Model has a hasMany-Relationship with parts of this form.

```
Text hasMany Proofs
```

This is the validation-array:

```
var $validate = array(  
   'freetext' => array(  
      'between' => array(  
          'rule' => array('between', 250, 1000),  
          'message' => '..',  
      ),  
   ),  
);
```

Here is an example of the data passed to the controller

```
[Proof] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [freetext] => asd
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [freetext] => asd
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [freetext] => asd
            )
    )
```

I use the following code to validate:

```
$this->Texts->set($this->data);   
if ($this->Texts->validates()) {
```

When I call it, it returns true, so the validation succeed. BUT freetext has a bit less than 250 chars.

But: The form shows the red asterisks, which symbolizes me, that the validation-array is succesfully parsed an applied to the form.
And also in the corresponding controller `beforeValidate() { debug($this->data); }` shows me the correct data.

So WHY does data validation succeed, even when the policies are not me?

Thanks ahead!
~MxAgent

Comment: I believe your Model calls should be singular, not plural - "Text", not "Texts".  Also, isn't 'beforeValidate()' a model method, not a controller action?

Comment: This is just because I changed some names due to sensible data..

Comment: Is it a problem, that the field is not existing in the table but in the validation-array and in the form. I need to process the data, the user entered and then write it partly into another fields..

Comment: `foreach($this->data['Proof'] as $proof) { $proof = array('Proof' => $proof); $this->Proof->set($proof); if (!$this->Proof->validates()) echo "err";}` works! Validation fails, BUT no message is displayed to the corresponding field..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to cakePHP 2.0 and used `validateMany()` for validation. Now it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

A quick jump into the CookBook (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1154/between) reveals that your format seems to be incorrect. Try this(drop the "between" array):

```
var $validate = array(  
   'freetext' => array(  
          'rule' => array('between', 250, 1000),  
          'message' => '..',  
   )  
);
```

Comment: Another "quick jump into the CookBook" shows an example like the one he's using:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/133/Multiple-Rules-per-Field

Comment: Ah, you're right, my bad!
But looking at that section, I think he shouldn't be calling the rule "between" as it might be causing conflicts.

Comment: Agree that naming it 'between' might be confusing, but I don't THINK that's an issue.

Comment: I changed the validate-array to exactly what the tutorial says.. but it didn't change the result :(